# Percentage symmetry

Tags: recreational-mathematics, average, percentages

I am currently reading `Investing in the Unknowns and Unknowable by Richard Zeekhauser`.

On page 6, 3rd paragraph, there is following lines:

`Thus, if a price 100 goes up or down by an average of 3 each year or up by a ratio of 103/100 or down by 100/103 hardly matters. But change that 3 to a 50 and the percentage symmetry helps a great deal. The price becomes 100(150/100) or 100(100/150), which has an average of 117.`

I am not able to work out how he got 117.

Comment: Me neither, since those two expression have an arithmetic mean of 108.333... and a geometric mean of 100.

Comment: So I had sent him a query and he was kind enough to respond, saying he made a mistake. It should be 108.33.

Comment: So, is your question still relevant or not?

Comment: Not relevant anymore.